# 2 bit up 4 bit counter with D flip flops - VHDL

Tags: vhdl, counter, bit

Hello i have been trying to write VHDL code for this Schematic.
The counter should start counting when enable sents a signal. When enable is deactivated then the counting stops. If enable sents another signal then the counter starts counting from the value that it stopped the lasttime.

[image]

At first i created the D Flip Flop code.

```
library ieee;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
  use ieee.std_logic_unsgined.all;

entity dff is
  port(d,rst,clk: in std_logic;
        q: inout std_logic);
end  dff;

architecture rtl of dff is
  begin
    process (clk, rst)
begin
  if (rst='0') then
    q<='0';
  else
    if(clk='1' and clk' event) then
      if (d='0') then q<='0';
    else q<='1';
  end if;
end if;
  end if;
end process;

end rtl;
```

After that i tried to implement the main schematic, and this is the code that i wrote.

```
library ieee;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
  use ieee.std_logic_unsgined.all;

entity updff is
  port (rst,clk:in std_logic;
        q: inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end updff;

architecture rtl of updff is
component dff is
  port(d,rst,clk: in std_logic;
        q: inout std_logic);
end component;

signal a,b,c,d,e,f : std_logic;

begin
  a<=not q(0);
  D1 :
   dff
   port map(
   a,rst,clk,q(0)
   );

  b<=(q(0) xor q(1));

  D2 :
   dff
   port map(
   b,rst,clk,q(1);
   );

  c<= q(0) and q(1) xor q(2);

  D3 :
   dff
    port map(
    c,rst,clk,q(2)
    );

    d <= q(0) and q(1);
    e <= d and q(2);
    f <= e xor q(3)

  D4 :
   dff
   port map(
   i,rst,clk,q(3)
   );
end rtl;
```

So i writing to kindly ask you your opinion because i am a bit confused with the `D1, D2, D3, D4` implementation.

Comment: The idea of an HDL language is that you do **not** think in gates but in functionality. It is a 4 bit counter with enable and reset. You can write the core of that in about six lines of code. To me this smells very much like home work.

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you facing?

Comment: @oldfart basically no. I am just trying to learn by examples.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am not sure of how am i implementing D1 - D4 . By that i mean i dont know if the input data (signals a,b,c,f)  of every D are right .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many methods to describe counters in VHDL.

If you want to implement counter with structural way, your implemented method is current way but it will be better if you use vectors instead of simple signals. It make code very clear and readable.

- in your ddf module one of IF statement can be removed
- in counter you don't want use q in input mode,so better way for use that is define internal signals and assign thats to q

**For Example You can Bellow Style :**

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY dff IS
    PORT
    (
        clk     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
        rst : IN  STD_LOGIC;
        din : IN  STD_LOGIC;
      qout  : OUT STD_LOGIC
    );
END dff;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF dff IS

BEGIN

    PROCESS (clk, rst)
    BEGIN
        IF (rst = '0') THEN
            qout<='0';
        ELSIF(clk = '1' AND clk'EVENT) THEN
            qout <= din;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;

END behavioral;
```

and for describe counter bellow style:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
ENTITY upcount4 IS
    PORT
    (
        clk     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
        rst : IN  STD_LOGIC;
        en      : IN  STD_LOGIC;
      qout  : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END upcount4;


ARCHITECTURE rt_level OF upcount4 IS

    COMPONENT dff IS
        PORT
        (
            clk     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            rst : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            din : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            qout    : OUT STD_LOGIC
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL dffs_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL dffs_in : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL ands_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN

    ands_out(0) <= en AND dffs_out(0);
    ands_out(1) <= ands_out(0) AND dffs_out(1);
    ands_out(2) <= ands_out(1) AND dffs_out(2);

    dffs_in(0) <= en XOR dffs_out(0);
    dffs_in(1) <= ands_out(0) XOR dffs_out(1);
    dffs_in(2) <= ands_out(1) XOR dffs_out(2);
    dffs_in(3) <= ands_out(2) XOR dffs_out(3);

    qout <= dffs_out;

    dff_0:dff 
    PORT MAP
    (   
        clk  => clk,
        rst  => rst,
        din  => dffs_in(0),
        qout => dffs_out(0)     
    );
    dff_1:dff 
    PORT MAP
    (   
        clk => clk,
        rst => rst,
        din => dffs_in(1),
        qout=> dffs_out(1)      
    );

    dff_2:dff 
    PORT MAP
    (   
        clk => clk,
        rst => rst,
        din => dffs_in(2),
        qout=> dffs_out(2)
    );

    dff_3:dff 
    PORT MAP
    (   
        clk => clk,
        rst => rst,
        din => dffs_in(3),
        qout=> dffs_out(3)      
    );

END rt_level;
```

> When module instantiations are same parameters, we can use a beautiful statement called `FOR GENERATE`. you can use bellow style:

```
ARCHITECTURE rt_levelgen OF upcount4 IS

    COMPONENT dff IS
        PORT
        (
            clk     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            rst : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            din : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            qout    : OUT STD_LOGIC
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL dffs_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL dffs_in : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL ands_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN

    ands_out(0) <= en AND dffs_out(0);
    ands_out(1) <= ands_out(0) AND dffs_out(1);
    ands_out(2) <= ands_out(1) AND dffs_out(2);

    dffs_in(0) <= en XOR dffs_out(0);
    dffs_in(1) <= ands_out(0) XOR dffs_out(1);
    dffs_in(2) <= ands_out(1) XOR dffs_out(2);
    dffs_in(3) <= ands_out(2) XOR dffs_out(3);

    qout <= dffs_out;

    generate_label:
    FOR index in 0 to 3 GENERATE
        dffs_0_3_label:dff 
        PORT MAP
        (   
            clk  => clk,
            rst  => rst,
            din  => dffs_in(index),
            qout => dffs_out(index)     
        );
    END GENERATE;
END rt_levelgen;
```

If You don't want implement counter with structral model, you can describe it in behavioral model and implementation tool (e.g Vivado or ISE) will converts it to actual hardware.(for example register with adder)
bellow code describes an upcounter in behavioral model:

```
ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF upcount4 IS

    SIGNAL counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
    PROCESS(reset,clock)
    BEGIN
        IF(reset = '0') THEN
            counter <= (OTHERS => '0');
        ELSIF( RISING_EDGE(clock) )THEN
            IF(enable = '1') THEN
                counter <= counter + X"1"; 
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
    qout <= counter;

END behavioral;
```

**Test Bench Module and wave form**

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY counter_tb IS
END counter_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF counter_tb IS 

    COMPONENT upcount4
    PORT(
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         rst : IN  std_logic;
         en : IN  std_logic;
         qout : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;

   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal rst : std_logic := '0';
   signal en : std_logic := '0';

   signal qout : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

BEGIN

   uut: upcount4 PORT MAP(
        clk => clk,
         rst => rst,
         en => en,
         qout => qout);

    clk <= NOT clk AFTER 5 NS;

    rst <= '0', 
             '1' AFTER 30 NS;

    en  <= '0', 
             '1' AFTER 40 NS, 
             '0' AFTER 70 NS, 
             '1' AFTER 90 NS;

END;
```

[image: Simulation Waveform]

Good-lock!

Comment: could you provide a test bench to understand better the flow?

Comment: I added testbench code and waveform to end of answer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! You helped me a lot :)